# состояние checkbox html после get запроса!

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, get

Выполняю WEB проект, где запросы GET и POST к бэкенду необходим без ajax. Есть фильтр рубрик(чекбоксы),вопрос, как сохранять chekbox enabled или выключать их после get запроса?

Answer (score 0):

Сохраняете состояние в бэке, а состояние на фронте каждый раз ставите по значению из бэка.